# Banding in Perlin Noise (Haxe)

Tags: haxe, noise, perlin-noise

I'm using [this implementation of Perlin Noise](http://ncannasse.fr/blog/optimizing_perlin_noise) to generate bitmaps in Haxe. Here's the code in which I use the linked implementation:

```
var bd = new BitmapData(100,100,false,0xffffffff);
var op = new OptimizedPerlin(Std.random(10),8,0.5);
op.fill(bd,100,100,100);
var b:ByteArray = bd.encode("png", 1);
var fo:FileOutput = sys.io.File.write("/develop/test.png", true);
fo.writeString(b.toString());
fo.close();
```

Some of the results are smooth and what I expect Perlin noise to be, basically:

[image: Smooth noise example]
[Imgur link here](https://imgur.com/kWKF0vO)

However, a large proportion of the results have a weird banding in them, like this:

[image]
[Imgur link here](https://i.imgur.com/TcZmhPy)

Since no-one else mentions this anywhere when discussing the implementation, on both the original blog and the subsequent links, I figure I must be doing something wrong. Am I missing anything?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure but it could be a problem with numbering of verices in Perlin noise algorithm.

Comment: As in, 2D versus 3D? Ok. I'll take a look. I don't know if I can flatten this to 2D only... @blazejmar

Comment: Could you also provide the values for offset, number of octaves and falloff for both images?

Comment: There are 8 octaves with a falloff of 0.5 (the latter two values in the constructor call in my attached code snippet). Offset is not set by me, and I'm not sure what the values are either...

Comment: When you're calling fill function you're providing offset. Could you post these parameters?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. My parameters for fill() are in the snippet above: 100,100,100. But these aren't the offset params. iXoffset, etc. in the source code are not set by me.

Comment: So these 2 images were generated using exactly same code?

Comment: Yeah. Just a different seed. If it helps, I've just noticed that this only happens on the neko target. mac and flash work fine.